# dnsmasq content filter

Tags: dnsmasq, content-filter

Is it possible so use `dnsmasq` as a selective content filter (just for specified clients - defined by their MAC address)

I know how to create a global content filter.

I know that a proxy should be used for this kind of stuff but I'm looking for a basic lightweight solution (but I don't want to use OpenDNS or any similar services... it has to be local).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the authors site :

> Dnsmasq is a lightweight, easy to configure DNS forwarder and DHCP
>   server. It is designed to provide DNS and, optionally, DHCP, to a
>   small network. It can serve the names of local machines which are not
>   in the global DNS. The DHCP server integrates with the DNS server and
>   allows machines with DHCP-allocated addresses to appear in the DNS
>   with names configured either in each host or in a central
>   configuration file. Dnsmasq supports static and dynamic DHCP leases
>   and BOOTP/TFTP/PXE for network booting of diskless machines.

So the answer is, no, you can't use dnsmasq as a content filter. Unless you only intend to maintain a blacklist of domains so `dnsmasq` will not forward them at all. But of course you can do this with any DNS server, I wouldn't call this a *content filter*.

You can maintain a hosts file in dnsmasq and map all of them to 127.0.0.1, the parameter to use is `--addn-host=samplehostsfile.txt`.

Comment: Sorry for my expression... I need a basic blocker of provided domains... And I know what dnsmasq is for... I just wanted to know if there's a way... thanks

Comment: Yes, there is see my edit.

Comment: Yes but the main problem is that I don't want to block all clients on the LAN... just a few computers... that was the point of my question...

Comment: And the answer is no :) not just with `dnsmasq` .